# MySQL Connector for .NET - Is it REALLY mature?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

After spending a miserable month with MySQL/.NET/EntityFramework, my findings:

Support for Entity Framework is VERY primitive, please use it for student-subjects type of database. Kindly do not consider it using for serious development as they ARE STILL unable to sort out VERY BASIC things like:

- it DOES NOT support unsigned stuff
- it DOES NOT support unsigned columns as FK; if you try, it gives you a beautiful exception; "The specified value is not an instance of a valid constant type\r\nParameter name: value" [http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44801]
- blob cannot store more then few KB;
- cannot compare null object with a column with a LEGAL null value [http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49936]
- they are unable to write VERY PRIMITIVE check to return date as null if value in column is 0000-00-00 00:00:00
- if you use Visual Studio; sorry; mysql/sun guys hate Microsoft, they will NOT LET you import more then two or three tables (for Micky Mouse type of tables, they allow five; but thats it) - if you try, it will throw TIME OUT error on your face ... unless you are smart enough to change the connection time in connection string

**Anyone who would like to add in above list?**

WISH I would have seen a list like this before I selected MySQL :(

Comment: Would using a ODBC connection solve some of these issues?  I know its not ideal but may get your project working.

Comment: Just started a personal side project and will be using this and didn't realize there were so many bugs..

Comment: @John M: ODBC is dinosaur-era thing:

Comment: @corymathews: Good luck :) ... to work on this; you will be needing google and a brick : google to search for absurd exceptions - brick to bang your head with when deadlines will fly-by...

Comment: @effkay hum then I better go find a brick, or ~10k for mssql.

Comment: what about sql-express? this project of mine is slipping by two weeks.. just because of this decision :(..

Comment: @corymathews: I am not open-source hater / MSFT lover. I just want to meet deadlines - I love to meet deadlines. The reason of this post is not degrade anything: rather to help make an 'informed' decision. My client wanted MySQL/ASP .NET - there was almost no time for proper RnD (yea this is everyone's story) - wish I had knew, I would have 'highly' recommended PHP/MySQl.

Comment: No doubt about it, ASP.Net + MySql = deadline overflow.

Comment: Giving this a try in 2012 and I would still not recommend it. Some of the above bugs seem to be fixed (FK), but there must still be others. I am left banging my head after working with this for two weeks. I have to use MySql, so I am back to using good ol' (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection()).... Stick to php+mysql or asp.net+sqlserver

Comment: I'd like to add the FK unsigned thing is still an issue. I'm using v6.8.3 along with Entity Framework 6 and I spent a good 15 minutes going "WTF?" does "The specified value is not an instance of a valid constant type\r\nParameter name: value" mean. Finally worked it out with this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql .NET Connector is indeed miserable. I'm quitting now my efforts on supporting it on my current project. The support/documentation is very poor and the functionality is indeed VERY primitive. Work a little bit with FKs, uints, DateTime and Guid and you'll see how hell looks like.

I expected Sun to invest some more on it...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they only have [one guy](http://www.reggieburnett.com/) working on it. Look through the [MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/list.php?38) and you'll see how long it even took them to get an alpha out the door. I'm not surprised they still haven't managed to get some of the basics right

Answer (score 1):

I use MySQL Connector 6.0.3 on a variety of .NET applications.

Most of the work I do is the 'basic' SQL type stuff - SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE and for this the connector works fine.

Issues I have relate to lack-of-documentation - most of the emphasis for .NET applications is on using MSSQL and not MySQL.

Comment: obviously Microsoft will promote its own products - but now that Sun has acquired MySQL and MySQL is one of the major data bases and I guess shooting for the best; I believe they should invest on drivers as well. Like Oracle; they have most mature drives and they are as good as Microsoft's.

Answer (score 1):

[I have had my own share of problems with the Compact Framework version, which is the same source with a few #ifdefs.](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/05/connecting-to-a-mysql-database-on-the-net-compact-framework/)